# How to use translate in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Hi I am new to angularjs world. I am doing registration page and my app contains English and Arabic pages. I am storing English and Arabic words in JSON files. This is my index.html file.

```
<body ng-app="RoslpApp">
    <div ng-controller="RoslpAppController">
        <div class="popup">
            <label>Language</label>
            <select ng-model="selectedItem">
                <option>العربية</option>
                <option>English</option>
            </select>
            <button ng-click="clickHandler(selectedItem)">Submit</button>
            <ul id="nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="Registration">Registration</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="container">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my main.js file.

```
var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    $stateProvider
           .state('Registration', {
               url: '/Registration',
               templateUrl: 'Registration/Registration.html'
           });
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('Registration');
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: "/scripts/Locales/{part}/{lang}.json"
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de_EN');
});
app.run(function ($rootScope, $translate) {
    $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
        $translate.refresh();
    });
});
app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
    $scope.clickHandler = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);
    };
}]);
```

This is my registrationcontroller.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('RegistrationController', ['$rootScope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('Registration');
        var isPartAvailable = $translatePartialLoader.isPartAvailable('Registration');
        if (isPartAvailable) {
            $translate('Fname').then(function (data) {
                $rootScope.PageSubTitle = data;
                console.log($rootScope.PageSubTitle);
            });
        }
    }]);
})();
```

This is my Registration.html. I am posting only one field to save space.

```
<label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="FirstName" class="FirstName" translate="yes" >
```

This is my de_EN.json file.

```
{
    "Fname":"Fnamein English"
}
```

I have arabic file also. I am not able to translate Fname in the above code. May I get some help here to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.[image: Folder structure]

Comment: if you change this <input type="text" id="FirstName" class="FirstName" translate="yes" > into 
<input type="text" id="FirstName" class="FirstName" translate  value="Fname">
would this help ?

Comment: Thank you. It does not work.

Comment: can you upload simple code on jsfiddle i believe it is simple error that you have i might be able to debug it

Comment: Thank you. I created Plunker. Please find the below link. https://plnkr.co/edit/m57BI5pivGzXD9UtwVtm?p=preview

Comment: When i copy all code ui-routing not working now. Whenever i click on Registration tab corresponding Registration.html file in ng-view. Please help me on this.

Comment: i am working on it give me some time

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: for ur ui-routing issue it is quite simple you need to include
    <script src="RegistrationController.js"></script>
in index.html

Comment: Thank you. In visual studio it is working fine. When i copied to Plunker i forget to include reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 after debuging the plnkr i fount the solution 

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    $stateProvider
           .state('Registration', {
               url: '/Registration',
               templateUrl: 'Registration.html',
               controller: 'RegistrationController'
           });
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('Registration');
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: "{lang}.json"
    }); 
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de_AR');


});
// app.run(function ($rootScope, $translate) {
//     $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
//         $translate.refresh();
//     });
// });

------------------
    i also edited index.html head part


      <title>Raya Financing</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.8" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script data-require="angular-translate@*" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.5.0/angular-translate.js"></script>
           <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

        <script src="angular-translate-loader-partial.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Main.js"></script>
         <script src="custom.js"></script>
        <script src="menu.js"></script>
        <script src="RegistrationController.js"></script>



        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you. It is not working. I made above changes. I am concerned about RegistrationController and Registration.html

Comment: just change the head inside index.html  as code above and in Main.js as above it will work it is working fin on my plnkr

Comment: I changed but it is not working. May i have link of your Plunker?

Comment: <h1>{{ 'Fname' | translate }}</h1> This is correct right?

Comment: also in your input should be like this 
                    <input type="text" id="FirstName" class="FirstName"  value="{{'Fname'| translate}}">

Comment: Thanks. It is working but I have Registration.html file as you see in Plunker. I want to change the contents of that page. Is that possible?

Comment: sure , in your RegistrationController.js  use 
    $translate.use("lanuage here");
and in your Registration.html just edit the input as i mentioned in the previous comment
is there anything else ?

Comment: Thank you. In my RegistrationController i have   $translate('Fname').then(function (data) {
                $rootScope.PageSubTitle = data;
                console.log($rootScope.PageSubTitle);
            }); So i should repeat this line of code for each words?

Comment: you don't need that at all you should put each word you need to translate as {{'Fname'| translate}} in html pages -check the input in prvious comment .
if you please mark my solution as answer it would be appreciated (Y)

Comment: Hi Msalam, I found the problem i have  Argument 'RegistrationController' is not a function, got undefined this error when my Registration.html page loads.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add controller reference in index.html. I am good now. thank you.